# How to reproduce the same layout of a MessageBox in a new window?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am searching for a way to create a "Yes to all - Yes - No - No to all" message box. I first tried to use a MessageBox instance but I understood that it is impossible to add custom buttons to it. So here I am with a custom window I created myself which does what I want but its design is far from being at least not ugly.

So my question is: How to reproduce the same layout of a MessageBox like below but with extra buttons?

[image: MessageBox]

Comment: How? Are you asking for anyone to do it for you or what is your question? Create window with two buttons, an image and some other elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a lot of examples of custom message boxes, both for WPF and WinForms.

**I'm very sorry** about amount of text, but here is detailed explanation and code examples.

As @mm8 suggested, the easiest way is to create simple `Window`, build layout for Header (Caption), Icon, Message and Buttons.

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WPFApp.CustomMessageBox"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title=""
        MinHeight="150"
        Width="500" 
        SizeToContent="Height"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        WindowStyle="None"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        Background="Transparent"
        FontSize="14"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid Margin="5" Background="White">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="64"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="28"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Border for our custom message box -->
        <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
                Grid.RowSpan="3" 
                BorderBrush="Gray" 
                BorderThickness="1" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Border.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="4" 
                                  ShadowDepth="0"
                                  Direction="270" 
                                  Color="Black" 
                                  RenderingBias="Performance"/>
            </Border.Effect>
        </Border>
        <!-- Header of our message box to keep Caption and to be used for window move -->
        <TextBlock x:Name="CMBCaption" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                   Grid.Row="0" 
                   Text="Custom Message Box Caption"
                   Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                   Background="Gainsboro"
                   Foreground="Black"
                   FontWeight="SemiBold"
                   Margin="1,1,1,0"
                   Padding="5,2.5,0,0" 
                   MouseLeftButtonDown="OnCaptionPress"/>
        <!-- Icon for our custom message box -->
        <Image x:Name="CMBIcon" 
               Grid.Column="0" 
               Grid.Row="1" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
               VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
               Width="36" 
               Height="36"/>
        <!-- TextBlock for message content. Wrapped into Label because of alignment needs -->
        <Label Grid.Column="1" 
               Grid.Row="1" 
               VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
               Margin="2,24,4,24">
            <TextBlock x:Name="CMBMessage" 
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       Text="Custom Message Box Message"/>
        </Label>
        <!-- Background for button block -->
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" 
                   Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                   Fill="Gainsboro"
                   Margin="1,0,1,1"/>
        <!-- Buttons block -->
        <StackPanel x:Name="CMBButtons"                    
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    FlowDirection="RightToLeft" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                    Margin="0,0,6,0"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

So here is `TextBlock` ("CMBCaption" for our Caption), `Image` ("CMBIcon" for our icon), `TextBlock` ("CMBMessage" for our message, putted into `Label` as Content property to make correct alignment) and `StackPanel` ("CMBButtons" for some amount of buttons). "CMB" (if not obvious) is
abbreviation of CustomMessageBox.
That will give you simple little window, which can be movable (by `MouseLeftButtonDown="OnCaptionPress"` handler on Caption TextBlock), looks simple and fresh, is stretchable (depending on content size) and has `StackPanel` at bottom to store any amount of buttons you wish.

[image]

**Code-behind:** (check comments and remarks below)

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using Brushes = System.Windows.Media.Brushes;

namespace WPFApp
{
    public partial class CustomMessageBox : Window
    {
        // Field that will temporarily store result before we return it and close CustomMessageBox
        private static CustomMessageBoxResult result = CustomMessageBoxResult.OK;


        // Buttons defined as properties, because couldn't be created (initialized) with event subscription at same time "on-the-fly".
        // You can add new different buttons by adding new one as property here
        // and to CustomMessageBoxButtons and CustomMessageBoxResult enums   
        private Button OK
        {
            get
            {
                var b = GetDefaultButton();
                b.Content = nameof(OK);
                b.Click += delegate { result = CustomMessageBoxResult.OK; Close(); };
                return b;
            }
        }
        private Button Cancel
        {
            get
            {
                var b = GetDefaultButton();
                b.Content = nameof(Cancel);
                b.Click += delegate { result = CustomMessageBoxResult.Cancel; Close(); };
                return b;
            }
        }
        private Button Yes
        {
            get
            {
                var b = GetDefaultButton();
                b.Content = nameof(Yes);
                b.Click += delegate { result = CustomMessageBoxResult.Yes; Close(); };
                return b;
            }
        }
        private Button No
        {
            get
            {
                var b = GetDefaultButton();
                b.Content = nameof(No);
                b.Click += delegate { result = CustomMessageBoxResult.No; Close(); };
                return b;
            }
        }            
        // Add another if you wish


        // There is no empty constructor. As least "message" should be passed to this CustomMessageBox
        // Also constructor is private to prevent create its instances somewhere and force to use only static Show methods
        private CustomMessageBox(string message,
                                 string caption = "",
                                 CustomMessageBoxButtons cmbButtons = CustomMessageBoxButtons.OKOnly,
                                 CustomMessageBoxIcon cmbIcon = CustomMessageBoxIcon.None)
        {    
            InitializeComponent();
   
            // Handle Ctrl+C press to copy message from CustomMessageBox
            KeyDown += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.C))
                    Clipboard.SetText(CMBMessage.Text);
            };

            // Set message
            CMBMessage.Text = message;
            // Set caption
            CMBCaption.Text = caption;

            // Setup Buttons (depending on specified CustomMessageBoxButtons value)
            // As StackPanel FlowDirection set as RightToLeft - we should add items in reverse
            switch (cmbButtons)
            {
                case CustomMessageBoxButtons.OKOnly:
                    _ = CMBButtons.Children.Add(OK);
                    break;
                case CustomMessageBoxButtons.OKCancel:
                    _ = CMBButtons.Children.Add(Cancel);
                    _ = CMBButtons.Children.Add(OK);
                    break;
                case CustomMessageBoxButtons.YesNo:
                    _ = CMBButtons.Children.Add(No);
                    _ = CMBButtons.Children.Add(Yes);
                    break;
                case CustomMessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel:
                    _ = CMBButtons.Children.Add(Cancel);
                    _ = CMBButtons.Children.Add(No);
                    _ = CMBButtons.Children.Add(Yes);
                    break;  
                // Add another if you wish                 
                default:
                    _ = CMBButtons.Children.Add(OK);
                    break;
            }

            // Set icon (depending on specified CustomMessageBoxIcon value)
            // From C# 8.0 could be converted to switch-expression
            switch (cmbIcon)
            {
                case CustomMessageBoxIcon.Information:
                    CMBIcon.Source = FromSystemIcon(SystemIcons.Information);
                    break;
                case CustomMessageBoxIcon.Warning:
                    CMBIcon.Source = FromSystemIcon(SystemIcons.Warning);
                    break;
                case CustomMessageBoxIcon.Question:
                    CMBIcon.Source = FromSystemIcon(SystemIcons.Question);
                    break;
                case CustomMessageBoxIcon.Error:
                    CMBIcon.Source = FromSystemIcon(SystemIcons.Error);
                    break;
                case CustomMessageBoxIcon.None:
                default:
                    CMBIcon.Source = null;
                    break;
            }
        }


        // Show methods create new instance of CustomMessageBox window and shows it as Dialog (blocking thread)

        // Shows CustomMessageBox with specified message and default "OK" button
        public static CustomMessageBoxResult Show(string message)
        {
            _ = new CustomMessageBox(message).ShowDialog();
            return result;
        }

        // Shows CustomMessageBox with specified message, caption and default "OK" button
        public static CustomMessageBoxResult Show(string message, string caption)
        {
            _ = new CustomMessageBox(message, caption).ShowDialog();
            return result;
        }

        // Shows CustomMessageBox with specified message, caption and button(s)
        public static CustomMessageBoxResult Show(string message, string caption, CustomMessageBoxButtons cmbButtons)
        {
            _ = new CustomMessageBox(message, caption, cmbButtons).ShowDialog();
            return result;
        }

        // Shows CustomMessageBox with specified message, caption, button(s) and icon.
        public static CustomMessageBoxResult Show(string message, string caption, CustomMessageBoxButtons cmbButtons, CustomMessageBoxIcon cmbIcon)
        {
            _ = new CustomMessageBox(message, caption, cmbButtons, cmbIcon).ShowDialog();
            return result;
        }


        // Defines button(s), which should be displayed
        public enum CustomMessageBoxButtons
        {
            // Displays only "OK" button
            OKOnly,
            // Displays "OK" and "Cancel" buttons
            OKCancel,
            // Displays "Yes" and "No" buttons
            YesNo,
            // Displays "Yes", "No" and "Cancel" buttons
            YesNoCancel,
            // Add another if you wish
        }

        // Defines icon, which should be displayed
        public enum CustomMessageBoxIcon
        {       
            None,
            Question,
            Information,
            Warning,
            Error         
        }

        // Defines button, pressed by user as result
        public enum CustomMessageBoxResult
        {
            OK,
            Cancel,
            Yes,
            No
            // Add another if you wish
        }


        // Returns simple Button with pre-defined properties
        private static Button GetDefaultButton() => new Button
        {
            Width = 72,
            Height = 28,
            Margin = new Thickness(0, 4, 6, 4),
            Background = Brushes.White,
            BorderBrush = Brushes.DarkGray,
            Foreground = Brushes.Black
        };

        // Converts system icons (like in original message box) to BitmapSource to be able to set it to Source property of Image control 
        private static BitmapSource FromSystemIcon(Icon icon) =>
            Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(icon.Handle, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

        // Handler on CustomMessageBox caption-header to allow move window while left button pressed on it
        private void OnCaptionPress(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
                DragMove();
        }
    }
}
```

**Remarks.**

First of all, to simulate original `MessageBox` and call it only with `CustomMessageBox.Show()` (not with `new CustomMessageBox().Show()` as regular window) you should hide window constructor by making it `private`.

Enums `CustomMessageBoxButtons`, `CustomMessageBoxIcon` and `CustomMessageBoxResult` are replacements for `MessageBoxButton`, `MessageBoxIcon` and `MessageBoxResult` enums from original `MessageBox`.

Each Button stored as private property in `CustomMessageBox` class. On Buttons added to `StackPanel` on `switch` statement. They added in order to lay *"from right to left"* (so first added button will be at most right, next - left of first etc.).

`GetDefaultButton` method returns, as commented, simple button with pre-defined properties. You can customize it in any way, using gradients, styles, magic - whatever. Even you can remove it and set different style for each `Button` in its property (in `private Button OK`, `private Button Cancel` I mean) to make OK button green, Cancel button red, Yes button pink etc. `GetDefaultButton` may be rewrited to some kind of common `GetButton` if you want one method to create any button with specified text and click action as arguments:

```
private static Button GetButton(string buttonText, RoutedEventHandler clickAction)
{
    Button button = new Button
    {
            Width = 72,
            Height = 28
           // and other
    };
    button.Content = buttonText;
    button.Click += clickAction;
    return button;
}

// In switch statement, when adding buttons to StackPanel, you create and add it instantly
private CustomMessageBox(...)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // ...
    switch (cmbButtons)
    {
        case CustomMessageBoxButtons.OKOnly:
            _ = CMBButtons.Children.Add(GetButton("OK", delegate 
                                                        { 
                                                            result = CustomMessageBoxResult.OK;
                                                            Close(); 
                                                        }));
            break;
        // ...
    }
}
```

`private static BitmapSource FromSystemIcon` methods, again, as commented, uses default `MessageBox` icon (or if correct, System Icon) to convert it to `BitmapSource`. It is needed, because you can't set System Icon to default WPF `Image` control as Source. If you want to use own icons/images you can remove it and rewrite `switch` statement where icons set to `CMBIcon.Source` with paths (URIs) to your own icons/images.

`private void OnCaptionPress` is handler from `TextBlock` which stores Caption (or is Header) of CustomMessageBox. Because in XAML `WindowStyle` property setted to "None" - we can't move window as it is borderless, so this handler uses header to move window until left mouse button pressed on it.

This `CustomMessageBox` doesn't have **Close** (**x**) button. I don't add it because each dialog button has `Close()` call at click action. You can add if you wish, but this have no sense.

I set window Width property to 500px, so it stretches only by heigth. You also can change it, even make resizable or return WindowStyle to default value (with minimize, maximize and close buttons).

I've also added different "Caption" TextBlock background color in `switch` statement where icon sets to make MessageBox be better perceived "by eye", but code is huge enough so I removed it from example.

**And finally.**

To add your `Yes to all`, `No to all` or other buttons, on this example, I placed comments `// Add another if you wish` in places, where you should add new ones:

1. Add `YesToAll`, `NoToAll` or other entries to `CustomMessageBoxButtons` enum to be able specify it when call, for example, as `CustomMessageBox.Show(..., ..., CustomMessageBoxButtons.YesToAllNoToAll)`.
2. Add also entries to `CustomMessageBoxResult` enum to be able return them as result.
3. Add new Button property, named `YesToAll`, `NoToAll` or anyway you need. Set a `.Content` property with text, that should be displayed on this button ("Yes to all", "No to all" etc.). Add `.Click` handler, in which set `result` field with `CustomMessageBoxResult` enum value of this button and put `Close()` method to call window close.

And usage is simple, as original `MessageBox`:

```
private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var result1 = CustomMessageBox.Show("Some message");
    var result2 = CustomMessageBox.Show("Some message", "My caption");
    var result3 = CustomMessageBox.Show("Some message", "My caption", CustomMessageBoxButtons.OKOnly);
    var result4 = CustomMessageBox.Show("Some message", "My caption", CustomMessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, CustomMessageBoxIcon.Warning);

    // Do whatever with result
}
```

Few examples:

- [Only message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mb3yT.jpg)
- [Message + Caption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naR7o.jpg)
- [Message + Caption + Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ms6T3.jpg)
- [Message + Caption + Buttons + Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1gjU.jpg)

*I **specially** removed `Yes to all`, `No to all` button from example to allow you try create it by yourself. You have, i think, detailed guidance now.*

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't expected such a complete answer