# How open WPF Window in static c# Window and read from Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, window, static-methods

I want to call a WPF window via Code Behind and display it in my application, no matter where I am in the application. What I am failing at is that the static method that calls the window is not allowed to continue in the code until I have clicked a button. OK or Cancel. I can't manage that at the moment.
The OK button should then read a value from the text box and then process it in the method. When opening the WPF window, a value should be entered in the text box, if available.

I have tried the following:

My WPF window.

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.Views.UC.TextboxAndButtons"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.UC" 
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Height="105" Width="200"
    FontFamily="Arial"
    WindowStyle="None"
    Closing="WindowClosing"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"        
    >
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModels:TextboxAndButtonsViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="32"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Please, input some text if you wish" 
               FontWeight="Bold"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1"
             Height="16"
             Margin="5" 
             Text="{Binding UserText, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" 
                Orientation="Horizontal" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Content="OK" 
                Width="80" 
                Height="24" 
                Margin="10,0"
                Command="{Binding OkCommand}" />
        <Button Content="Cancel" 
                Width="80" 
                Height="24" 
                Margin="10,0"
                Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" />
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

My TextboxAndButtons.Xaml.cs:

```
 public partial class TextboxAndButtons : Window
{

    private readonly TextboxAndButtonsViewModel textboxAndButtonsViewModel;
    public TextboxAndButtons()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.textboxAndButtonsViewModel = new TextboxAndButtonsViewModel();
        this.DataContext = this.textboxAndButtonsViewModel;

        if (this.textboxAndButtonsViewModel.CloseAction == null)
        {
            this.textboxAndButtonsViewModel.CloseAction = this.Close;
            this.textboxAndButtonsViewModel.DialogResultValue = this.DialogResult;
        }
    }

    public string UserText
    {
        get
        {
            return this.textboxAndButtonsViewModel.UserText;
        }

        set
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            {
                this.textboxAndButtonsViewModel.UserText = value;
            }
        }
    }


    private void WindowClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.DialogResult = this.textboxAndButtonsViewModel.DialogResultValue;
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }


}
```

My ViewModel Class:

```
public class TextboxAndButtonsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    public TextboxAndButtonsViewModel()
    {
        this.OkCommand = new RelayCommand(this.OkCommandExecuted);
        this.OkCommand = new RelayCommand(this.CancelCommandExecuted);
    }

    public bool? DialogResultValue { get; set; }

    private void CancelCommandExecuted(object obj)
    {
        this.DialogResultValue = false;
        this.CloseAction();
    }

    private void OkCommandExecuted(object obj)
    {
        this.DialogResultValue = true;
        this.CloseAction();
    }

    private string userText;

    public string UserText
    {
        get => userText;
        set
        {
            //userText = value;
            // Prism
            SetProperty(ref this.userText, value);
        }
    }

    public Action CloseAction { get; set; }

    public ICommand OkCommand { get; private set; }
    public ICommand CancelCommand { get; private set; }

    
}
```

My static method from any class:

```
            public class TextWrapper
{
    private static TextboxAndButtons textboxAndButtons;

    public static string TextBoxValue { get; set; }

    public static string CallTextboxWindow(string userText)        
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.DataBind, new Action(() =>
        {
            TextBoxValue = TextBoxWindow(userText);
        }));

        return TextBoxValue;
    }
    private static string TextBoxWindow(string userText)
    {
        string text = "";

        try
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.DataBind, new Action(() =>
            {
                textboxAndButtons = new TextboxAndButtons();
                textboxAndButtons.UserText = userText;

                textboxAndButtons.Owner = Application.Current.Windows.Cast<Window>().LastOrDefault(x => x.IsActive) ?? Application.Current.MainWindow;
                textboxAndButtons.ShowDialog();

                if (textboxAndButtons.UserText != userText)
                {
                    text = textboxAndButtons.UserText;
                }
            }));


            // Check text
            /// {......}
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error = ex.Message;
            string inner = ex.InnerException.ToString();
        }

        return text;
    }        
}
```

With the dispatcher I have come closer to the goal, but it doesn't quite work yet.

With this code above I have the following behaviour:
(It calls the method "CallTextBoxWindow(string userText)" from the outside).

When I start my application and I set a breakpoint in the class TextWrapper --> method CallTextBoxWindow(string userText) --> at "return TextBoxValue;" it jumps there, which is NOT correct. It should only go there when the OK button in the WPF window is clicked. If I let the code continue at the breakpoint, then the window is displayed, I can enter text, click the OK button, but then it is no longer in the method. If I now click the OK button, the window closes and that's it.

If I only use Invoke with the dispatcher, then I have the strange behaviour that I cannot enter anything in the text box.

My goal would be to build it as an MVVM, but I would also be happy with a variant in which it works at all.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you want some kind of `MessageBox`, but for user input instead of notify.

There are tonns of examples of "How to create custom `MessageBox`'es". For current issue i'll use idea from my [own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69723465/how-to-reproduce-the-same-layout-of-a-messagebox-in-a-new-window/69729911#69729911).

So, first of all you need to create a separate Window (view) with your `TextBox` for user input and OK/Cancel buttons.

**UserTextInputWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="YourNamespace.Views.UserTextInputWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:YourNamespace.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="UserTextInputWindow" 
        Name="This"
        WindowStyle="None"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Height="200" 
        Width="400">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModels:UserTextInputViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="32"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Please, input some text if you wish" 
                   FontWeight="Bold"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" 
                 Margin="5" 
                 Text="{Binding UserText}"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" 
                    Orientation="Horizontal" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Content="OK" 
                    Width="100" 
                    Height="24" 
                    Margin="10,0"
                    Command="{Binding OkCommand}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=This}"/>
            <Button Content="Cancel" 
                    Width="100" 
                    Height="24" 
                    Margin="10,0"
                    Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=This}"/>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

That one looks like below. Ofc, you can customize it as you wish.

[image]

As can be seen in XAML, i use `UserTextInputViewModel` class as ViewModel for this window and its code-behind is:

**UserTextInputViewModel.cs:**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using YourNamespace.Commands;

namespace YourNamespace.ViewModels
{
    public class UserTextInputViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _userText;
        // Our binded to TextBox property, which stores user's input
        public string UserText
        {
            get => _userText;
            set
            {
                _userText = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        // A command for OK button
        // ParameterizedCommand is custom implementation of ICommand interface
        private ICommand _okCommand;
        public ICommand OkCommand => _okCommand ??= new ParameterizedCommand(commandParameter => (commandParameter as Window)?.Close() );

        // A command for Cancel button
        // ParameterizedCommand is custom implementation of ICommand interface
        private ICommand _cancelCommand;
        public ICommand CancelCommand => _cancelCommand ??= new ParameterizedCommand(commandParameter =>
        {
            // On Cancel we should "reset" user input
            UserText = string.Empty;
            (commandParameter as Window)?.Close();
        });

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) =>
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

`ParameterizedCommand` implementation is simple wrapper over some `Action` with `object` as parameter, so that Action can be binded through `Command` property to `Button` in XAML.

**ParameterizedCommand.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace YourNamespace.Commands
{
    public class ParameterizedCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Action<object> _action;

        public ParameterizedCommand(Action<object> action) => _action = action;

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;
        public void Execute(object parameter) => _action(parameter);

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }
}
```

So, in fact, that ViewModel just stores user input and handles OK/Cancel buttons clicks by closing window (and resetting user input on cancel).

And finally, code-behind of `UserTextInputWindow` itself, where I hide default constructor and replaced it call with a static method `Show`:

**UserTextInputWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
using System.Windows;
using YourNamespace.ViewModels;

namespace YourNamespace.Views
{
    public partial class UserTextInputWindow
    {
        // Hiding default constructor by making it private
        private UserTextInputWindow() => InitializeComponent();

        // Introducing static method, which should display window and return
        // user input string.
        // Note, that this is blocking call (because of ShowDialog inside).
        // Also note, that I add some useless parameter "topmost" just to avoid
        // conflicts with standart Window.Show method
        public static string Show(bool topmost = false)
        {
            // Securing ourselves by checking access from non-STA thread
            return Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess() 
                 ? ShowWindowAndGetUserInput() 
                 : Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(ShowWindowAndGetUserInput);
        }
    
        private static string ShowWindowAndGetUserInput()
        {
            var userText = string.Empty;

            var  window = new UserTextInputWindow();
            window.Closing += delegate
            {
                if (window.DataContext is UserTextInputViewModel vm)
                    userText = vm.UserText;
            };

            window.ShowDialog();

            return userText;
        }
    }
}
```

My project structure for this example looks like this (irrelevant to this example items was painted):
[image]

Usage is pretty similar to `MessageBox`. It also available safely from any thread.

```
var userInput = UserTextInputWindow.Show();
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userInput)) { /* User input nothing or cancel */ }
```

Not sure that this is pure and correct MVVM approach, but it works. Feel free to correct me.

Comment: Thank you Auditive, I have implemented it, but it does not work. Same behaviour as with my code. WPF Window appears, but I can't enter any text in the textbox and the buttons don't react. Because of the buttons, I adapted something from your code. For the property IComannd I left out the parameterizedCommand, because I couldn't do anything with it. I therefore only used "ICommand OKCommand {get; private set;}".

Comment: Re-edit your question and provide new code samples you've used. Also, my example is copypastable, so you can just add a Window to your project with name `UserTextInputWindow`, paste XAML into it from answer (with namespaces correction), paste Window's code-behind part, and create a class with name `UserTextInputViewModel` with also pasting content from answer. I've edit ViewModel example and add ParameterizedCommand implementation, so you fully can use it "as is".

Comment: Auditive, thanks for your help, but unfortunately I have the same effect. The window opens, but I can't enter anything in the text box and the buttons don't react. 
I have revised my post and now put my current state with the complete code.

Comment: What you trying to achieve? I can't follow your logic. My example displays window, where user can input some text and that text returns as result after window closing. What does your `TextWrapper`? Why you need store window in a field? You need to define either user pressed Ok or Cancel buttons? Or just receive inputted text? Or provide some text to edit in that window and receive edited text? You need only 1 such window or have a possibility to open as much as you need at once?

Comment: Your code works and does exactly what it should, but only when I test it as a new project. As soon as I incorporate your example into my software. I can't enter anything in the textbox. The cursor flashes in the text box, but I can't enter anything. I can copy something into the text box, but only if I use the mouse. Right mouse button --> Paste. The problem must be the software, which is very old and complex. That's why I tried to use the dispatcher, but it didn't bring me the desired success. I'm still despairing and I'll have to find the solution for this strange behaviour myself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `SemaphoreSlim` to wait asynchronously until the window is closed to not block the UI thread:

```
public async Task OpenWindowAsync()
{
    using (SemaphoreSlim semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1))
    {
        string enteredText = null;

        TextboxAndButtons textBoxWindow = new TextboxAndButtons();
        textBoxWindow.Owner = System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows.Cast<Window>().LastOrDefault(x => x.IsActive) ?? System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow;
        textBoxWindow.SetText(setValue);

        textBoxWindow.Closed += (sender, e) =>
        {
            enteredText = textBoxWindow.GetText();
            semaphoreSlim.Release();
        };

        textBoxWindow.Show();

        await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(enteredText))
        {
            string a = enteredText;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why for any reason there should be Semaphore? What for?

Comment: @Auditive: The async `WaitAsync` method which lets you wait *asynchronously*. Read the answer again?

Comment: @Kojote: Did you try this?